# ORA-00936 :missing expression

Tags: oracle, syntax-error

can you explain where the mistake is? when I run the program a notification appears like ORA-00936: missing expression

```
Insert into vemp_10_20 (employee_id,last_name,hire_date,email,job_id,salary) values ('411','Michele',to date ( '17-Sep-2010','DD-MON-RRRR'),'michele@xyz.com','MK_REP','1000');
```

Comment: It would help you to learn to "read" error messages. Pretty much every front-end program you use to write and test your code will show you, not just the error code and error message, but the exact place in the code where that error was found. In your case, it would point you to the word `DATE` in `TO DATE`. Perhaps with that additional clue you would have been able to answer your own question.

Comment: @barbarosozhan: When the poster reports a syntax error in the code, it is best not to edit their code - that may inadvertently mask the error. (It doesn't in this case, but as a general principle, we should not touch code in this kind of questions.) I will restore the code to its original form and only remove the irrelevant tag, as you did.

Comment: The error is because of `TO DATE`, as already told.  And `TO_DATE` is not even necessary, as you want to insert a constant date. Use a date literal for that: `VALUES(411, 'Michele', DATE '2010-09-17, 'michele@xyz.com', 'MK_REP','1000');`.

Comment: I agree with you as a general case @mathguy , but *not* directly occurs *within this case* as you told.

Answer (score 1):

Function is `TO_DATE`, not `TO DATE` (missing underline `_`).

Also, consider using `YYYY` format mask, not `RRRR` (as you specify years in 4-digits format, which is correct).